# Twig loop bootstrap

Tags: loops, bootstrap-4, twig

How can I make twig loop, that goes like this? Tried batch and loop.index, but just couldn't make it work as expected.

```html
   
  <div class="col-lg-6">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
  </div>
```

Comment: Please share what you tried (your twig code), we'll help you with it...

Comment: You want the output to look exactly like the above?